# Dovecot configuration for user login from client side( outlook )

Tags: sendmail, dovecot

i have configured  Sendmail in centos 7 without error, when i start to configure Dovecot(incoming server), i don't know how to configure for IMAP and POP3 user logins. when i configure with outlook there is error in Incoming server.

[Error image 1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhoeK.png)

[Error image 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1gla.png)

Comment: What port are you telling Outlook to use for IMAP? Are you using TLS? Can you post your dovecot configuration? Your dovecot server logs? Can you try a manual telnet to your dovecot server and port?

Comment: telnet log is [here](http://justpaste.it/qa24) @Law29

Comment: dovecot_logs_is [here](http://justpaste.it/qa27) @Law29

Comment: I did only two things in dovecot.conf file which i mentioned in bold letter:

[Here](http://justpaste.it/qa28)@Law29

Comment: i didn't use any TLS..

Comment: I really don't know what to do with dovecot's daughter configuration file...please help me to access the incoming  server in outlook..